# How many characters can read by using the readline() method in java?

Tags: java, readline, iostream

I using `readLine()` method for reading the text, but i am not aware of how many text can read that method. Ex.

```
String str = in.readLine();
```

how many texts can read and store on "str"?

Comment: I'd recommend reading Javadoc of String, even looking at its sourcecode (the Java part, of course). Then you'll find Strings are not a space to fill, but an object with an array and stuff, so it can grow as much as you can dimension that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will read as many as are available until it encounters an eol

Answer (score 8):

[Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), but you obviously should not be running into this limit very often.

-- and note that this is because Integer.MAX_VALUE is the maximum size for a Java String

Comment: +1 - and note that this is because `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is the maximum size for a Java String.

Answer (score 1):

Till `LINE BREAK`, loosely speaking. For the exact, see Matthew's answer. Cheers.

Comment: This is not strictly true; see @Matthew's answer.

Comment: @Stephen: Cent percent agreement. I didn't think that much at that time ;).

Answer (score 0):

[This bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4107821) leads me to believe there is no limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ask this question you have a much bigger problem. Why are the lines you are reading so long that you need to worry about it? This is evidence of poor design upstream.